# Unexpected result from "greater than" comparison of values from a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experiencing a strange JavaScript/jQuery math bug when trying to determine whether one value is greater than another.

Here is a link, using jsFiddle, to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/qxeTj/

```
$("#Quantity").live("focusout", function() {
    var qty = +$(this).val();
    var stock = +$('#StockLvl').val();
    if (qty > stock) {
        $('#Result').html("<p>Quantity: " + qty + "</p><p>Stock: " + stock + "</p>" + "<p>Not Enough Stock.</p>");
    }
    else if (stock > qty || stock == qty) {
        $('#Result').html("<p>Quantity: " + qty + "</p><p>Stock: " + stock + "</p>" + "<p>Enough Stock.</p>");
    }
});
```

Example of problem:

When I focus out of the `input` field, if it has a value of `1` or `2`, it works fine. It even works if I have a value of `3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

But the problem is then when I use values from `10-19` or `100-199` or `1000-1999` and so forth. It say's it has enough stock when it shouldn't.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/E4PaD/

Comment: FYI, instead of `stock > qty || stock == qty`, just do `stock >= qty`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're comparing strings. Convert them to numbers first.

```
var qty = Number( $(this).val() );
var stock = Number( $('#StockLvl').val() );
```

or

```
var qty = +$(this).val();
var stock = +$('#StockLvl').val();
```

or

***This way will be safest in your case.***

```
var qty = parseInt( $(this).val(), 10 );
var stock = parseInt( $('#StockLvl').val(), 10 );
```

Comment: Ahh ofcourse! parseInt();. I'm so stupid sometimes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with string comparison not number. Put a parseInt around the values and you will get the expected result.